# Data Set for training, validation and prediction

Tags: neural-networks, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, prediction

I had multivariate data which has total number of data is 70. I want to separate the data set in three subset of data into training, validation and prediction. The forecast is on one. Therefore the data will become, 68 data for training, 1 validation and 1 for prediction. Is it reliable to divide data where only used 1 data set for validation? Or is there any suitable method to divide the data to make prediction more reliable.

Comment: How many data points are in each dataset? If the number of points is small, cross-validation might be more robust. Even if the number of points is large, it's common practice to use larger proportions of your total dataset for validation/testing than you currently propose.

Comment: I like the question. Normally, the cross validation would be the answer for me. However, it is designed for the training - validation splitting. The author of this question asks for the solution in the training - validation - testing split.

Comment: @liangjy Training- 68 data, 1 validation and 1 prediction.  I have on 70 data. How to do cross validation?

Comment: @KarelMacek how to do cross validation?

Comment: You can Google for it. You simply leave one out, fit the model, calculate the error for the entry that was not used. So far the approach is the same as you describe. The trick is that you repeat this process for each entry so you have 70 error values. Then you can play with them, calculate average, plot histogram etc.

Comment: @KarelMacek if  i got lower RMSE so the model is satisfy?

Comment: Yes, especially for the interpolation
 when you expect that future data will be in the same area as the original data set.

Comment: @KarelMacek So i need to split the data for three subset (training, validation and prediction), and then use cross validation to justify the model accuracy?